# Interrupt number confussion

Tags: linux

On my system (OpenSUSE 11.4 - kernel 2.6.37) **ifconfig** indicates different interrupt number for **eth0** than proc aqd sys file system.

ifconfig indicates 17:

```
linux-3e1w:~ # ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:19:F5:0E:2D  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:17
```

proc fs indicates 43:

```
linux-3e1w:~ # cat /proc/interrupts
           CPU0       CPU1       
  0:    6340443     635232   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:       5100        940   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  ..........
 17:     185626     257326   IO-APIC-fasteoi   firewire_ohci, b43
 43:          1          2   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
 ........
NMI:        483       2065   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:    3140034    5437332   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:        483       2065   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RES:     230706     229157   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:      10511      11305   Function call interrupts
TLB:      24196      26573   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:         72         70   Machine check polls
ERR:          9
MIS:          0
```

sys fs indicates 43:

```
linux-3e1w:~ # cat /sys/class/net/eth0/device/irq 
43
```

Can you explain it?

Update:

Relevant part of `lspci -vv` output for irq 17 (this belongs to *wlan0* and not to *eth0*):

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
        Region 0: Memory at f8000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=2 PME-
        Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
        Capabilities: [e8] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [d0] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-
   ....................
   ....................
```

Relevant part of `lspci -vv` output for irq 43:

```
 08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 02be
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 43
        Region 0: Memory at fc500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
        Capabilities: [40] Vital Product Data
                Product Name: Broadcom NetLink Gigabit Ethernet Controller    
                Read-only fields:
                        [PN] Part number: BCM95784M
                        [EC] Engineering changes: 106679-15
                        [SN] Serial number: 0123456789
                        [MN] Manufacture ID: 31 34 65 34
                        [RV] Reserved: checksum good, 25 byte(s) reserved
                End
        Capabilities: [60] Vendor Specific Information: Len=6c <?>
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee0300c  Data: 41c9
        Capabilities: [cc] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <1us, L1 <64us
                        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
                LnkCtl: ASPM L0s L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-, Selectable De-emphasis: -6dB
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
        Capabilities: [13c v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-22-19-ff-fe-f5-0e-2d
        Capabilities: [16c v1] Power Budgeting <?>
        Kernel driver in use: tg3
```

Comment: lspci -vv output, please.

Comment: @bdonlan Added lspci output

Comment: Why close votes? This is real questions - several utilities output different interrupt number.

Comment: these are migration votes, to move this question to superuser. The question isn't being closed so much as recategorized.

Comment: And, would it be possible to get _full_ lspci -vv output, to see where that IRQ 17 is _really_ going?

Comment: Added lspci -vv output for irq 17 too. This belongs to wlan0 device, so I under impression that ifconfig prints incorrect interrupt for eth0. From other side, why ifconfig doesn't print interrupt number for wlan0? Can I trust output of sys and proc fs more than of ifconfig?

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your card is running in [MSI interrupt mode](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/MSI-HOWTO.txt), not legacy PCI mode. `ifconfig` is showing the legacy interrupt number assigned to your card by PCI configuration, rather than the MSI number assigned by `pci_enable_msi`.

The precise cause is visible in the `tg3` driver. The driver copies the legacy PCI irq into the `netdev` struct [at probe time](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/tg3.c?v=3.0#L15003). This is the number that `ifconfig` sees. The driver then [enables MSI at device open time](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/tg3.c?v=3.0#L9156), changing the IRQ number.

(It's doubtful that the interrupt and io addresses have any relevance to userspace on current hardware. Having this information in `ifconfig` dates from the ISA period, where we set card interrupts with jumpers. We only really need this information when debugging drivers now.)

Comment: Does MSI need interrupt? If no, than ifconfig output is misleading.

Comment: MSIs are interrupts, just a different type. This is really best thought of as a (minor) bug in the tg3 driver

Comment: Is sys or/and proc reliable sources of #irq number? I mean if it displays incorrect #irq than interrupts won't be handled.

Comment: Both '/sys' and '/proc' are correct. `ifconfig` displays the wrong interrupt number for the tg3 driver when in MSI mode, but it really doesn't matter. The value in `/proc` is the value that the driver is actually using.

Comment: Can I trust sys fs too?

Comment: Yes - sysfs shows the actual interrupt number of the device, and proc shows the number that the driver registered. They should be the same.